# How to use openenc to encode opus in ogg extension

Tags: file-conversion, opus

Musicbee uses opusenc to encode files into opus. I would like to encode my music files into opus in an ogg extention.

The command line arguments look like this:

`--bitrate 256 --vbr --ignorelength - [outputfile]`

I've tried `--bitrate 256 --vbr --ignorelength - [outputfile].ogg` and `--bitrate 256 --vbr --ignorelength - ogg`

I've looked at the [documentation](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opus-tools/ws/man/opusenc.html) and I don't know how I would do this.

Answer (score 1):

To encode a PCM Wave file `foo.wav` as an Ogg Opus file `foo.ogg` at 256 kb/s VBR:

```
opusenc --bitrate 256 foo.wav foo.ogg
```

VBR is the default so the `--vbr` option is not necessary.

You can use `--ignorelength` if the length in the Wave file header is wrong and you want it to assume that the audio continues to the end of the file with nothing after it, but by default it will do that if the length appears to be wrong so this should not normally be necessary.

Options such as `--title` and `--artist` may be used if you want to add tags.  See `opusenc --help` for the available options.

If you want to convert a whole directory, use a for loop.

- bash: `for f in *.wav; do opusenc --bitrate 256 "$f" "${f%.wav}.ogg"; done`
- Windows cmd: `for %F in (*.wav) do opusenc --bitrate 256 "%F" "%~nF.ogg"`

In addition to Wave files, `opusenc` will also accept AIFF and raw PCM input, and can optionally be built to accept FLAC and Ogg/FLAC input.  If you need to convert from some other format then try [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: tried ${f%.wav}.ogg for as an argument for musicbee but it didn't work.

Comment: That is bash syntax; you would type that into a bash shell.  You asked how to do it with opusenc.  Shell "programming" is borderline but if you are asking how to use a Windows GUI music player application then your question is definitely out of scope for this site.  Ask on the MusicBee forum, not on a programming site.